# JodaTime Checking if two times is in a period

Tags: java, time, jodatime, localtime

I have two times start time and end times and I put it in JodaTime Local time as this :

```
    LocalTime localStartTime = new LocalTime( hoursStartTimeInt, minutesStartTimeInt);
    LocalTime localEndTime = new LocalTime( hoursEndTimeInt, minutesEndTimeInt);
```

I want to compare if these times are between 12:00 - 06:00. please help thanks.

Comment: can you put some examples? you mean betweeen 6:00 and 12:00 of same day? or you mean 12:00 and 6:00 of next day?

Comment: Actually there is a money system and I needed to compare it if its on exact time I need to add an extra to it. and it starts from 12pm to 6am of next day

Answer (score 1):

You can create two `LocalTime` for `12:00` and `06:00` and compare it with your start and end time, like this:

```
        LocalTime localStartTime = new LocalTime( hoursStartTimeInt, minutesStartTimeInt);;
        LocalTime localEndTime = new LocalTime( hoursEndTimeInt, minutesEndTimeInt);;

        LocalTime twelveTime = new LocalTime(12,0);
        LocalTime sixTime = new LocalTime(06,0);
        localStartTime.isAfter(twelveTime);
        localStartTime.isBefore(sixTime);
        localEndTime.isAfter(twelveTime);
        localEndTime.isBefore(sixTime);
```

Comment: I assume 12:00 to 6:00 are on same day.

Comment: so why OP does not write from 06:00 to 12:00 ?? ;)

Comment: Yes I wanted to use isAfter and isBefore but I didnt know how does this work because I dont have date to compare to eg 11am can be also after that 12 if its next day how does this even work??